# Ratio occurrences of ($x \operatorname{AND} x^{-1} = 0$) to ($x \operatorname{AND} x^{-1} > 0$) for some range $[0...n]$, $x \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Represent $x \in \mathbb{N}$ in binary notation and $x^{-1} \in \mathbb{N}$ as the reverse of the binary digits of $x$.

**Examples**

Applying bitwise $\operatorname{AND}$ operations

$x\operatorname{AND}x^{-1} > 0$

```
11101101101 AND 10110110111 = 10100100101
```

$x\operatorname{AND}x^{-1} = 0$

```
1001100100110 AND 0110010011001 = 0000000000000
```

**Ratio Definition**

Define a range $[0...n]$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and let

$A =$ number of times $x\operatorname{AND}x^{-1} = 0$ occurs

$B =$ number of times $x\operatorname{AND}x^{-1} > 0$ occurs

The ratio is given by

$\large \frac{A}{B}$

**Ratio Examples**

Notice as $n$ grows, the ratio $\large \frac{A}{B}$ decreases as follows

```
For n=50, A=16, B=34  A/B=0.4706
For n=500, A=81, B=419  A/B=0.1933
For n=5000, A=594, B=4406  A/B=0.1348
For n=50000, A=3789, B=46211  A/B=0.0820
For n=4000000000 A=28143703, B=3971856297  A/B=0.0071
...
...
...
```

**Questions**

As $n \to \infty$, does the ratio $\large \frac{A}{B} \to 0$?

Does this imply $x\operatorname{AND}x^{-1} > 0$ is always true since  $x\operatorname{AND}x^{-1} = 0$ occurrences vanish?

Comment: Probably easier to restrict to $n=2^k-1$ first.

Comment: The last statement is nonsense. First, this isn’t about probability, because there is no uniform random natural number. And it clearly can happen that the value is $=0.$ You might show that the density of such $x$ is zero, but that does not mean that $>0$ is “always true,” or even “almost always true,” because density is not the same as probability, and density doesn’t work as a measure on subsets of $\mathbb N.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a start, looking at the case when $n=2^{k+1}-1.$ Specifically, if the values $A_n,B_n$ Correspond to values $x<n,$ the we have a subsequence of $A_n/B_n$ which converges to zero.

I have the feeling some details might be slightly off, but the approach is sound.

In the numbers between $2^k$ and $2^{k+1}-1,$ inclusive, there are $2^k$ values. Of those, there are $$\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor (k-1)/2\rfloor}2^j\binom{\lfloor (k-1)/2\rfloor}{j}\tag1$$ with the value $$x\operatorname{AND} x^{-1}=0.\tag2$$

This is because, if we think of the digits as a subset of $f(x)\subset\{0,1,2,\dots,k\},$ with $k\in f(x).$ $x$ satisfies $(2)$ if  $\forall a,b\in f(x),$ $a+b\neq k.$ This means we can think of $f(x)$ as a subset $T\subseteq \left\{1,\dots,\lfloor (k-1)/2\rfloor\right\}$, plus a choice of exactly one element $\{a,k-a\}$ for each $a\in T.$ There are $2^{|T|}$ such choices. (Note, it is never true for such $x$ that $a=k-a.$)

This means the number of $T$ with this property of size $j$ is $\binom{\lfloor (k-1)/2\rfloor}{j},$ so you get the sum formula $(1).$

So for $x\leq 2^{k+1}-1,$ you get:

$$\begin{align} 
A_{2^{k+1}}&=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor (i -1)/2\rfloor}2^j\binom{\lfloor (i -1)/2\rfloor}j\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor(k-1)/2\rfloor}2^j\sum_{i=2j+1}^{k} \binom{\lfloor (i -1)/2\rfloor}j
\end{align} $$

When $k=2q$ is even:

$$A_{2^{k+1}}= \sum_{j=0}^{q-1}2^{j+1}\binom{q+1}{j+1}=3^{q+1}-1-2^{q+1}$$

And with $B_{2^{2q+1}}=2^{2q+1}-1-A_{2^{2q+1}}$ you get $\dfrac{A_{2^{2q+1}}}{B_{2^{2q+1}}}\to0$ as $q\to\infty.$

But this only proves for a subsequence of $A_n/B_n.$